# Android weird behavior of custom ArrayList Adapter and Cursor

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, cursor, adapter

I have a custom ArrayList adapter of my object. In this Adapter i create a cursor with the id provided by the arrayList `deals`.
I have two different layouts for the items in the Listview which depends if the cursor has data in it or not.
The problem is that scrolling up and down for some time causes the listview to show the same cursordata multiple times on different items. The data from the arrayList is shown correctly.

pic: http://s1.directupload.net/images/140530/a7cz9ztt.png

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    holder = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;

    cursor = db.getDealInfo2ID(deals.get(position).getId());
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    if(row == null){
        holder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        if(count==0){
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
            holder.comment = null;
        }

        else{ 
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_row_deal_layout, null);
            holder.price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.toDealButton);
            holder.comment =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        }

        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dealName);
        holder.degree = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.degree);
        holder.thermoColor = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoColor);
        holder.thermoGrey = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoGrey);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }

    else{
        holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
        if(holder.comment==null && count !=0){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_row_deal_layout, parent, false);

            holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dealName);
            holder.degree = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.degree);
            holder.thermoColor = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoColor);
            holder.thermoGrey = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoGrey);

            holder.price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.toDealButton);
            holder.comment =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
    }

    //ShortCard befüllen
    holder.name.setText(deals.get(position).getName());
    Integer deg = deals.get(position).getDegree();
    setDegreeViews(Math.abs(deg.intValue()),deg);

    if(count!=0){
        // DtailCard befüllen
        fillDetailCard(cursor);

    }
    cursor.close();
    return row;
}

private void fillDetailCard(Cursor cursor) {



    //Preis
    String priceString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLDataBaseHelper.COLUMN_PRICE));
    if(priceString!=null)
        holder.price.setText(priceString);

    //DirectLinkButton
    String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLDataBaseHelper.COLUMN_DIRECTLINK));
    if(url!=null){
        holder.button.setText(R.string.directDeal);
        holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.to_deal_button_background);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonDirectToListener(url, context));
    }
    else{
        holder.button.setText("");
        holder.button.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(null);
    }

    //Kommentar-Anzahl
    holder.comment.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLDataBaseHelper.COLUMN_COMMENTCOUNT)));

    //Pic
    String pic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLDataBaseHelper.COLUMN_PIC));
    if(pic!=null){
        holder.icon.setBackground(null);
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(null);
        picasso.load(pic).error(R.drawable.error).into(holder.icon);
    }
    else{
        holder.icon.setBackground(null);
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(null);
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            holder.icon.setBackgroundDrawable(defaultImage);
        } else {
            holder.icon.setBackground(defaultImage);
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```

I dont really see where the problem is. Hope you can help.

Comment: i don't understand why you are using a cursor in an arrayadapter. why not use a cursor adapter?

Comment: i know there is an cursor adapter. i cant say for shure that the id/item is in the database.

Comment: ok. just curious. where does the id come from, then?

Comment: (btw, the issue is probably that you are calling fillDetailCard(cursor); only if count != 0, resulting in duplicates when `count == 0`. You need to clear the content of these views in this case.)

Comment: hm when `count == 0` there shouldn´t be the detailed card anyway and any of those views in the detailed layout. i updated the opener with the `fillDetailCard` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your code carefully and I see that it may happen in the following scenario:

```
int count = cursor.getCount(); //returns 0
if(row == null){ //returns false and row is R.layout.card_row_deal_layout
```

In this case you omit all layout setup and skip calling fillDetailCard.

With this line `if(holder.comment==null && count !=0){` you check if layout should change from `layoutResourceId` to `R.layout.card_row_deal_layout` but you never check the opposite way.

It could look like this:

```
holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
if(holder.comment==null && count !=0){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_row_deal_layout, parent, false);
    holder = new Holder();
    holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dealName);
    holder.degree = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.degree);
    holder.thermoColor = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoColor);
    holder.thermoGrey = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoGrey);

    holder.price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
    holder.icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.toDealButton);
    holder.comment =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
    row.setTag(holder);
} else if (holder.comment != null && count == 0) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
    holder = new Holder();
    holder.comment = null;
    holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dealName);
    holder.degree = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.degree);
    holder.thermoColor = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoColor);
    holder.thermoGrey = row.findViewById(R.id.thermoGrey);
    row.setTag(holder);
}
```

**Update**

I have added creating new Holder for layout change suggested by the author of the question.

You need to understand that `ListView` re-use view components. If every component would create own `View` in case hundreds of items it would be a waste of memory. That's why `getView()` provide convertView which sometimes is not null. In those cases it means you are re-using view which is already setup with previous data.

Because you use 2 different layouts, you can't re-use convertView every time. For this cases you have implemented this if statement `if(holder.comment==null && count !=0)`. Unfortunately, it is changing layouts only one way `layoutResourceId` -> `R.layout.card_row_deal_layout` when small layout changes into more detailed layout. In case `convertView` is already `R.layout.card_row_deal_layout` with data from previous item and current item should be `layoutResourceId`, layout is not changed. Therefore, you needed `else if`.

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: thank you for your help. this almost fixed it completly. But i still got multiple items. You brought me to an idea. when the layout changes i didn´t create a new instance of the holder object. After adding this it runs correctly. But i still dont get why the `else if` is necessary. There is no chance in my logic that the layout changes from detailed to short but unfortunately this is necessary. i tought that the row object is binded to the position... can you explain that?